# Ошибка, подскажите в чем проблема

Tags: javascript

```
function deleteLi() {

    var findDelete = doc.getElementsByClassName("delete");
    for (var i = 0; i < findDelete.length; i++) {
        findDelete[i].onclick = function () {
            var findSelect = doc.getElementsByClassName("selected");
            findSelect.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
deleteLi();
```

При данном коде выводится такая ошибка, в чем проблема?

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'findSelect.style.display = "none"')
```

Comment: почему в первом случае ты бежал в цикле по результатам _getElementsByClassName_ а во втором нет?

Comment: согласен полностью, спасибо большое)